# Text displays on mouse release in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, text, drag-and-drop, collision-detection, draggable

Ok, I have a question about drag/drop, hittest and some text.

I have two objects, one of them is draggable. I want to display some text, when colission is detected, but only when mouse is UP (mouse is released).

How to do that?

This is part of the code that handles collision:

```
this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleCollision)
function handleCollision( e:Event ):void
{
    if(zuto.hitTestObject(tabla) && crveno.hitTestObject(tabla))
    {
        tekst.text = "GAME OVER"
    } else {
        tekst.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: You do that by reading the documentation and implementing the logic according to what you read. Then, if you run into problems, you post a question to SO with code that demonstrates the problem and we'll try to help.

Comment: I'm new here and new in as3 and Flash, so, cut me some slacks, ok? FN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should check if the mouse is down or not:

```
var mouseDown:Boolean;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_Up, onMouseUp);

function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseDown = true;
}

function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    mouseDown = false;
}

function handleCollision( e:Event ):void {
    if (mouseDown) { // mouse is still down, stop collision check
        return;
    }

    // ..rest of your code here
}
```